# Avg function not returning proper value

Tags: mysql, sql

I expect this query to give me the avg value from daily active users up to date and grouped by month (from Oct to December). But the result is 164K aprox when it should be 128K. Why avg is not working? Avg should be SUM of values / number of current month days up to today.

```
 SELECT sq.month_year AS 'month_year', AVG(number)
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date), "-", YEAR(DATE)) AS 'month_year', count(distinct id_user) AS number
    FROM table1
    WHERE date between '2020-10-01' and '2020-12-31 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(year_month FROM date)
    ) sq
    GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: You need to illustrate the problem you are having with sample data or perhaps a DB Fiddle.  I can point out that the outer query (if correctly written) is not doing anything.  You may intend that it actually do something.

Comment: The problem is there, on the title. Is giving me an incorrect value so I'm not sure if avg is doing its proper work

Comment: ok! I see your point now, the outer query is not doing anything so the avg() is not working. I'ts just giving me distinct id_user from the current month. How can I get the average? So making the outer query working?

Comment: Ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys thanks for your help. The problem was that on the subquery I was pulling the info by month and not by day. So I should pull the info by day there and group by month in the outer query. This finally worked:

```
SELECT sq.day_month, AVG(number)
FROM (SELECT date(date) AS day_month,
             count(distinct id_user) AS number
      FROM table_1
      WHERE date >= '2020-10-01' AND
            date < '2021-01-01'
      GROUP BY 1
     ) sq
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year_month FROM day_month)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use single quotes for column aliases!

```
SELECT sq.month_year, AVG(number)
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date), '-', YEAR(DATE)) AS month_year,
             count(distinct id_user) AS number
      FROM table1
      WHERE date >= '2020-10-01' AND
            date < '2021-01-01'
      GROUP BY month_year
     ) sq
GROUP BY 1;
```

Note the fixes to the query:

- The `GROUP BY` uses the same columns as the `SELECT`.  Your query should return an error (although it works in older versions of MySQL).
- The date comparisons have been simplified.
- No single quotes on column aliases.

Note that the outer query is not needed.  I assume it is there just to illustrate the issue you are having.

Comment: Hi! @gordonlinoff. Thanks for your help. But is still giving me an incorrect value even with your correction. I think it must be a different error :S

Comment: @AlexOrdóñez . . . Your comment is unhelpful.  What is the incorrect value?

Comment: The value is 168,505 and it should be 128K. Is not giving me an error but is not returning the proper value. It should return an average from daily active users whis is the count (distinct id_user)